# Procedure for dropping unique constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unique-constraint, sql-drop

I am trying to write a procedure to drop the Unique constraints from any table quicker.

```
IF EXISTS
        (SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.sysobjects 
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[dba].[spu_drop_uq_index]'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dba].[spu_drop_uq_index]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dba].[spu_drop_uq_index] (@table varchar(1000), @index varchar(1000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ['+@table+'] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+@index+']'
    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes WHERE name = @index)
        EXEC @sql
END    
GO

EXEC [dba].[spu_drop_uq_index] @table = 'aaa', @index = 'UQ_xxx'
GO
```

But I get an error:

```
The name 'ALTER TABLE [aaa] DROP CONSTRAINT [UQ_xxx]' is not a valid identifier.
```

However, if I execute this not dynamically, it succeeds:

```
ALTER TABLE [aaa] DROP CONSTRAINT [UQ_xxx]
```

What am I doing wrong? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 exec sp_executesql @sql
```

instead of `EXEC`, or put the `@sql` in parenthesis

```
 Exec (@sql)
```

`sp_executesql` is preferred: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx

> To execute a string, we recommend that you use the sp_executesql stored procedure instead of the EXECUTE statement. Because this stored procedure supports parameter substitution, sp_executesql is more versatile than EXECUTE; and because sp_executesql generates execution plans that are more likely to be reused by SQL Server, sp_executesql is more efficient than EXECUTE.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Also, use quotename instead of adding [ ] manually

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the exec string in brackets:

```
EXEC  (@sql)
```

When executing dynamic strings, brackets are required. When executing sprocs, they're not.